# "this" cannot be referenced to a nested function, how should I work around this?

Tags: javascript, dom

the reference for "this" doesn't reach the "timedFlip" function, how should I work around that? I'm fairly new to Javascript, I work mostly backend with Python.

```
function flipBack() {
    setInterval(timedFlip, 3000);
}

function timedFlip() {
    this.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
}

function flipCard() {
    cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log("User flipped " + cards[cardId].rank);
    console.log(cards[cardId].cardImage);
    console.log(cards[cardId].suit);
    cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].rank);
    this.setAttribute('src', cards[cardId].cardImage);
    checkForMatch();
}

function createBoard() {
    shuffle(cards);
    for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        var cardElement = document.createElement('img');
        cardElement.className = "cards";
        cardElement.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
        cardElement.setAttribute('data-id', i);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipCard);
        cardElement.addEventListener('click', flipBack);
        document.getElementById('game-board').appendChild(cardElement);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to refer to in the `timedFlip` function?

Comment: You can add next parameters in setTimeout and read them in timedFlip. setInterval(timedFlip, 3000, this); and then timedFlip(that) { that.setAttribute( ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind):

```
function flipBack() {
    setInterval(timedFlip.bind(this), 3000);
}
```